# How can I get the length N combinations for an array using lazy evaluation?

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation

I think I understand the difference between permutation and combination:

In short, `[1,20,30].permutation(3).map(&:sort).uniq` is the same as `[1,20,30].combination(3)`.

I currently have a program which gets all of an array's combinations:

```
array = [1,20,30,40,50,60]
1.upto(array.length).each do |combination_length|
  array.combination(combination_length).each do |combination|
    # ... do something here with the combination ...
  end
end
```

I'm trying to reduce the memory consumption and I think I should find an alternative to `array.combination(combination_length).each`.

The [Ruby docs for Lazy Enumerators](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) don't seem to show a `combination` method. The source for the `Array#combination` method is written in C, so I don't really have the skill to alter it.

What I'm specifically trying to do is run a block for each element of the `array.combination` results, but I *don't* want to load up all the length-N combinations into memory first.

I've looked around for an implementation of `combination` that I can understand, but I'm having a difficult time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"What I'm specifically trying to do is run a block for each element of the array.combination results, but I don't want to load up all the length-N combinations into memory first."

That is exactly what your code is doing. You are invoking the `combination` method without a block, which results in an Enumerator. Then you use its `each`method. Only one combination is in memory at a time.

Comment: So lazy evaluation is the default for Enumerator objects?

Comment: A very ehh.. lazy programmer could just generate an array and use it's `each` method, completely missing the point of having an Enumerator; but in general yes, Enumerators are lazy.